# Error Message: The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I get the error message "The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly" in Xamarin.Forms . I solution path changed but nevertheless i  displaying error message. I would appreciate if you help. Thanks.

```html
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Droid\obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\library_project_imports\res'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(ITaskItem item, Dictionary`2 acwMap)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(Dictionary`2 acwMap)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App1.Droid
```

This error mesage, i displaying during compilation. This code for example

```html
 MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "This is a text!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Try posting the code that is causing the error as well.

Comment: This error mesage, i displaying during compilation. This code for example 

MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

Comment: Please add that code to the original question. You can do that by pressing "Edit" on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your project to a location with short path.

For example :

Your original file location looks like : `c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App1\`

Copy and paste it into another location like `E:\App1`.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem while building the project.
Below is what has happened :

Cause :I copied my project folder from one location to another in same drive.
But my xamarin studio was still considering old project path

Solution : 
1.close current project

2.go to your project folder which you want to run.
example D:\Projects\my project\hybridappApp

3. locate you project solution file (Microsoft Visual Studio Solution (.sln))
4. double click the file and it opens the xamarin studion for you.
5. clean the solution and build before you run the project.

Hope this helps.